# jsonpath-plus prblem with key that start with @ character

Tags: jsonpath, json-path-expression, jsonpath-plus

I am using jsonpath-plus 6.01.
I have following JSON:

```
{
  "Request": {
    "@Domain": "SomeDomain",
    "Vehicle": {
      "@ID": "E11XPD"
    }
  }
}
```

I can execute following jsonpath expression:

```
$.Request['@Domain']
```

When I want to acces ID by expression:

```
$.Request.Vehicle['@ID']
```

I have following error: "Unknown value type".

I am using library this way:

```
import { JSONPath } from 'jsonpath-plus';
...
JSONPath({path: pattern, json: resultJson})
```

How can I access @ID value in this case?

Comment: Use ` for escaping. https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath-plus

Answer (score 2):

This definitely seems like a bug in the implementation. You're correct in that both of those should work.

I would suggest opening an issue with the implementation so that they can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This works in http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/

```
$.Request.Vehicle['@ID']
```

Comment: Is this example use  jsonpath-plus 6.01 library?